# GWT: how to know when a datagrid has finished rendering

Tags: gwt

Is there any way of knowing or handling when a datagrid has finished rendering without using any external library? I have tried to do it by using:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Command() {
  public void execute () {

  }
});
```

but in my case it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct solution. The `execute()` method is only called when a browser stopped doing anything else.

Browsers are single-threaded, so it's impossible that your DataGrid continues to render when `execute()` is called. You say "it's not working" - this means there is something else going on. For example, adding data or some browser events (mouse over, etc.) may trigger a refresh of the DataGrid. If you share the code, we may be able to help you find a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility to add a custom handler like `DataGridOnFinishRenderHandler` or anything else.

Comment: Could you rephrase this? Currently it gives the impression of being halfway between a (probably helpful) Singlish answer and an English request for help.